# Python and SQL - Best practice for managing changing Customer Data in a Order?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, database-design

At the moment I practice with Python and SQL a lot, and for now I am trying to create a Order Workflow with the Data saved inside an SQL Database for testing.

For example my Customer Table looks like this at the moment:

```
 CustomerSK CustomerID VersionID FirstName LastName Address DateEffective DateExpired  IsCurrent
 ---------- ---------- --------- --------- -------- ------- ------------- ------------ ---------
 42942      123        1         Robert    Smith    10001   2018-12-07    2019-12-22  0
 42943      123        2         Robert    Johnson  10002   2019-12-23    NULL        1
```

So I am trying to keep track of historical Data for a Customer, because if the Data for a customer changes I don’t want old orders to be affected.

**Works fine so far but I have a few questions:**

1. If an “Order”, at the moment I only have an Order Table which could contain an Inquiry also, is in active development with the customer, so not closed yet, and the Data for the Customer changes it needs to get the newest customer data if something like in the above shown Table happens (address or name changes). If the Order is closed it should keep a frozen status of the Data.

   How and where do I build such a process and what is the best approach to do that? Or am I doing something wrong in general?
2. Next question is: I would like to have Prefix for the IDs to give the user some help to remember the IDs. Like “CU” for Customer IDs and “AD” for addresses and so on. Should I save them also in the Database or only showing them in the GUI ?
3. If I am editing the Customer and want to create a new Version of CustomerID 123 but with Version 3, how does my SQL Query look like? Do I `update` or `insert` ? Or is there I way I don’t know yet to do that?

If I have missed some information in my question, please let me know!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> If an “Order”, at the moment I only have an Order Table wich could
>   contain a Inquiry also, is in active development with the customer, so
>   not closed yet, and the Data for the Customer changes it needs to get
>   the newest customer data if something like in the above shown Table
>   happens (address or name changes). If the Order is closed it should
>   keep a frozen status of the Data.
>   How and where do I build such a process and what is the best approach to do that? Or am > I doint something wrong in general?

You customer table is Slowly changing dimension (SCD) Type 2. One approach is to create your order tables as SCD type 2 and populate CustomerSK (FK) in your order tables based on 
CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN DateEffective AND DateExpired.

This way, you have 2 different version of orders and able to track it.

Other approach is to create a separate inquiry table and insert data in order when order is finalized or cancelled. (Hint: Trigger)

> Next question is: I would like to have Prefix for the IDs to give the
>   user some help to remember the IDs. Like “CU” for Customer IDs and
>   “AD” for addresses and so on. Should I save them also in the Database
>   or only showing them in the GUI ?

I would add a ID_FLAG (C/U) field in my table to check if id is for customer or address. All join/filter operation of string fields are costly.

> If I am editing the Customer and want to create a new Version of
>   CustomerID 123 but with Version 3, how does my SQL Query look like? Do
>   I update or insert ? Or is there I way I don’t know yet to do that?

You need to do a UPDATE THEN INSERT(UPSERT).
I am assuming you will be using a staging table to store modified (new data)

First step --> Update current records. Set end_dte =  CURRENT_DATE , VERSION = MAX(VERSION) + 1

Second --> INSERT NEW Record  with start_dte = CURRENT_DATE AND VERSION = MAX(VERSION) + 1

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer!
1. So i do get you right that my Order Table would also need to columns to save the customer, CustomerID and CustomerVersion?
2. But Customer and Address are two different tables, so they both need ID_FLAG right?

Comment: You only need CustomerSK field in your order table. For fetching customer information, you will join on this field and get all information. 


If these are 2 different tables then no need of flag. Just concat string (CU/AD) when selecting data from table

Comment: Okay, got it. I think one last question for now: While Inquiry Phase i want to have always the latest entry for customer and so on, after that if the Order Phase is done i want to freeze that data. Therefore you would do a different "Order Table" where you move the Inquiry Data to "freeze" them?